# Clear State After Submit React

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, state, submit

I'm trying to clear the previous state whether it be word or error that has a value on each new submit. Is this possible from the handleSubmit function? I've tried clearing the previous state by setting the state to an empty string after submit but that unfortunately didn't work.

```
  state = {
    word:'',
    error: '',
  };


handleChange = (event) => {
this.setState({word:event.target.value.toLowerCase()});
}


handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.search(this.state.word)
  this.setState({word: ''});
  this.setState({error: ''});

}


search = async (word) => {

  try{
      const data = await MerriamAPI.getWordInfo(word);
      console.log(data);
      //&& word exists 
      if (data.length && data[0].fl && data[0].meta.stems && data[0].hwi.prs[0].mw && data[0].shortdef[0]){
          console.log('A HERE')
          this.props.handleUpdate({
              word: word,
              info: data,
              versions: data[0].meta.stems,
              shortdef: data[0].shortdef[0],
              partOfSpeech: data[0].fl,
              pronunciation: data[0].hwi.prs[0].mw, 
          });
          this.props.setRedirect({
              path: `/definition/${word}`,
          });
      }
        else {
          console.log('B HERE')
          this.setState({error: 'Word Not Found'});
          console.log(this.state.error)
      }
  }
  catch{
      this.props.setModal('Offline')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do this and remove from the handle submit

```
this.props.handleUpdate({
  word: word,
  info: data,
  versions: data[0].meta.stems,
  shortdef: data[0].shortdef[0],
  partOfSpeech: data[0].fl,
  pronunciation: data[0].hwi.prs[0].mw,
});
this.setState({
  word: ''
});
this.setState({
  error: ''
});
this.props.setRedirect({
  path: `/definition/${word}`,
});
```

But if this code is a history push then you dont need to clear the state. And keep is mind once you change the state their will be re rendering.

```
this.props.setRedirect({
  path: `/definition/${word}`,
});
```